# Timer-Trigger not showing in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure so sorry if this does not make too much sense.

I created a function app in Azure that works when testing. I am trying to use Timer-Trigger to make this app run each morning. The issue I have is that Timer-Trigger Template is not available when I click add. I am going to

```
Home > Function App > "Choose My App Here" > Events
```

But Timer Trigger template does not show. Is it not possible to add timer-trigger to an existing function app?

Also tried

```
Home > Function App > "Choose My App Here" > Functions
```

but no luck here either.

Comment: Which language do you want to use? But general advise: do not create functions through the portal! Use a proper IDE

Comment: I want to use JS/node. I did just try this through VS Code but I get this
```
Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.
```

Going back through the CLI way, I see the option for timerTrigger instead of HTTP as I originally did during setup! Looks like the difference is in the function.json file. 

Working on getting it to actually send during timer since Im not able to get that far now. Thanks for mentioning the IDE!

Answer (score 0):

> But Timer Trigger template does not show. Is it not possible to add
> timer-trigger to an existing function app?

First, all Azure function based on script language and Windows OS should be able to create directly on the Azure portal. (Linux OS can not).

Second, I don't recommend you to create trigger directly on portal. If it is just a test, it is no problem, if you want to develop Azure function, I recommend you to use VS Code to develop Azure function, after finish the develop you can publish it to the Azure function.

Develop Azure function with VS Code needs four things: [Azure function core tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#v2) (I recommend you to use V3), [Azure function extension of VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2XLf.png), language environment and related language debug extension.

You can follow below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node

Use this button to deploy:

[image]

Or use function core tools command to deploy:

`func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>`

Or use web app zip deploy, ftp, git, anyway is ok, just upload local function app structure to azure function app physical path.

---

And the main structure of timer-trigger:

**`index.js`**

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    
    if (myTimer.isPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
};
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "* * * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below link will tell you the format of schedule:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```